# How to write XPath for HTML file in scrapy?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the content of from angel.co webpages which have HTML structure as

```
 <meta content="Panjo, Marketplace for enthusiasts, Santa Monica, E-Commerce, Payments, Social Commerce, Forums, jobs, recruiting, hiring" name="description">
```

So for above structure i am using Xpath

```
    hxs.('//meta/@content').extract()
```

it prints all text related to "content" tag but i want that this should print only content related to "description".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a predicate to only select the `meta` tag whose `name` attribute is `'description'`:

```
hxs.select('//meta[@name=\'description\']/@content').extract();
```

Here is a tutorial for the syntax of XPath: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: yeah it worked, actually i was using this hxs.select('//meta[@name='description']/@content').extract(), forgot to insert backlash, thanks...